# Convert background image in table cell to img tag without making any style difference

Tags: html, css

I have a table in a newsletter and I have a td like this

```
<td style="background:lightgrey;
background: url(https://dummyimage.com/700x600/666/fff.png)no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;"
class="squares-image">
</td>
```

What I would like to have is this:

```
<td style="background:lightgrey;" class="squares-image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x600/666/fff.png">
</td>
```

and have exactly the same result. What should I be doing?

Comment: Reproduced it in jsfiddle and they both work the same assuming you're setting their widths/heights etc.? You haven't posted much code so I can't tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? If this is because you need to support Microsoft Office Outlook on Windows (with its utterly atrocious support for HTML e-mail which hasn't improved since they made it 10x worse in Outlook 2007 by switching from MSHTML to Word's HTML engine) - then you're probably SOL. There's a reason Outlook has the big fat "Open in web-browser" button when you open HTML emails now.

Comment: I received a generated html newsletter to convert into a mailchimp editable custom template and I wanted to make those background images, `<img>`s to be able to easily edit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` combined with `object-fit`

```css
td {
  padding:20px 40px;
  position:relative;
}
td img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:lightgrey;
background: url(https://dummyimage.com/700x600/666/fff.png)no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;" class="squares-image">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:lightgrey;" class="squares-image">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x600/666/fff.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```